# Can't understand IE pseudo element height with display table

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am trying to achieve borders that are 85% the height of the div content. Each div needs to be as tall as the tallest item and the content is dynamically generated.

I am using :before and :after elements with a width and background to achieve this the border and display table-row, display table-cell to get the height working but am running into an issue with IE 10.

In IE the pseudo element seems to inherit the height of the content inside it's container, not the container.

example
http://jsbin.com/wazubu/edit?html,css
(apologies for the convoluted example, I'm coming from SharePoint with this and wanted to include some of the code I need in the final output)

[image: highlighted border issue, top is in chrome, bottom in IE 10]
I would appreciate any clarity anyone can bring to why this is happening. Works in FF the same as Chrome.

Comment: defaut of vertical-align for (table-)cell elements is middle.  IE minds it and set absolute element from middle. reset vertical-align along your display:table ... or add top:0 to your pseudo-elements   http://jsbin.com/voraqiwuki/1/edit?output

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus, do you have any idea why the height of the pseudo elements is that of the content and not inherited from the container?